# Oracle select with variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
Declare startdate date;
enddate date;
lastname nvarchar2(30);
Begin
Lastname := 'ZZZ';
startdate := '04-JAN-18';
enddate := '02-JUN-18';
insert into temp_feed
select empname, startdate, enddate , activityid, source, actname from emp_activity
where  startdate >=  startdate and enddate <=  enddate and lower(LASTNM) like lower(lastname||'%')
End;
```

when I hardcode date values its working fine, but when I use variables the result is null.

am I missing something?

Comment: What does 'failing' mean? Are you getting an error? Wrong results? What is the structure of `temp_feed`? (I think I've just spotted the issue...)

Comment: you have `lastname` variable declared as date, it should be varchar.

Comment: @AmithKumar sorry its a typo

Comment: @AlexPoole result set is null with variables, but when I use date directly in where clause its working fine. temp_feed is a table with the same structure as select.

Comment: your variable names are same as column names, use table alias to refer column.

Comment: I thought it was the name clash, but with the logic it should get lots more rows than expected - not nothing. I'm worried by your typos though, as that means you aren't showing us exactly what you are running - so the logic might not be what you showed either. Why not copy and paste your actual code into the question? Along with the structures of both tables.

Comment: Tip: Use ANSI date literals like  `DATE '2018-06-02'` which works whatever some crazy software is using a language setting. Also works on other databases.

Comment: How are you running this script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its recommended to use **V_** before the name of variables and also **P_** before the name of parameters, the problem in your code is you are comparing a value in table with itself at:

```
 startdate >=  startdate and enddate <=  enddate
```

I do format your code and use the standard naming format here:

```
DECLARE
   V_STARTDATE   DATE;
   V_ENDDATE     DATE;
   V_LASTNAME    NVARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   V_LASTNAME := 'ZZZ';
   V_STARTDATE := TO_DATE('04-JAN-18', 'DD-MON-YY');
   V_ENDDATE := TO_DATE('02-JUN-18', 'DD-MON-YY');

   INSERT INTO TEMP_FEED
      SELECT EMPNAME, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, ACTIVITYID, SOURCE, ACTNAME
      FROM EMP_ACTIVITY
      WHERE     STARTDATE >= V_STARTDATE
            AND ENDDATE <= V_ENDDATE
            AND LOWER (LASTNM) LIKE LOWER (V_LASTNAME || '%');
END;
```

Comment: It would be safe  to use date literals(for eg:- DATE '2018-01-04') or `to_date` instead of relying on implicit conversion from string literals for `v_startdate` and `v_enddate`. This might fail if op had a different NLS settings

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes you're right, I changed from implicit conversion to **to_date**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to convert your variable to Date format first.
if you use function and it gets an parameter from outside, we can **p_start_date** for a date. Then you can try to convert out parameter to date format for sure.

```
v_start_date := to_date(p_start_date,'dd-MON-yyyy') ;
```

also in where clause

```
to_date(startdate,'dd-MON-yyyy')  >=  to_date(p_start_date,'dd-MON-yyyy')
```

Comment: Its not working and lastname value is working fine problem is with the dates

Comment: can you share how did you defined "temp_feed"? or if you have chance to share whole this function, i can help you more. You can update your above question.